# Can I add multiple salesforce ORG from eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, force.com-ide, developer-org

I'm a newbie. I have added my developer org from eclipse [after installing force.com IDE]. But I want to add another org with it. Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible,

Make a new project(Force.com) and fill username and password

New - > Force.com Project - > Fill entries and enjoy

Mark it if useful